# How can I get the episode info dict from the on_sample_end callback?

Tags: ray, rllib

I need to get the episode info dict from the `on_sample_end` callback so that I can display some custom metrics every time a rollout has finished. How can I do that?
Ray Version: 0.7.3

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I need to be able to get the custom metrics variable so that I can display information after every achieved rollout.